# Git not adding updated files

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I make changes to any files in a repository that I'm working in and add them with `git add .` or `git add --all` and then commit, it says `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.

I made a temp directory, then checked out my master directory and merged with the following:

```
git checkout -b temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
```

I then tried to push the merged master to bitbucket but it says everything up to date, which I know it is not up to date.

When I look at the branches with `git branch -avvv` I see the following

```
* master                6070ba4 [origin/master] Merge branch 'temp'
  temp                  6070ba4 Merge branch 'temp'
  remotes/origin/master 6070ba4 Merge branch 'temp'
```

I'm not sure what the [origin/master] is under the comment for master, but I cannot figure out how to get this updated even after creating a temp branch.

The strange thing is when I checkout master, any updates I made are still there. Shouldn't the  new code be removed when I checkout a branch that had commits prior to my status now?

**Update: I restarted finder on my Mac and it now seems to be working. I never once changed my directory so I have no idea what was causing it.**

Comment: Can you type `git status` and post the output here?

Comment: says "nothing to commit". I just opened up a file, added "test" to it, saved it and used add --all. Tried again and still says nothing to commit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the files you were working on are untracked by git. You can check this in your .gitignore files.

You have your three branches (2 local and one on bitbucket (remotes/origin/master)) point to one commit (6070ba4), so everything is really up to date.

P.S. I'm unable to leave the comments so dont be to severe!

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me but git seems to behave correctly to me:

```
git checkout -b temp
```

This create a new branch and switches to it. No file changes.

```
git checkout master
```

This go back to master. If you were on master before you just created a branch pointing to the same commit at this point.

```
git merge temp
```

this merge temp with master. If you started from a master up to date everything is up to date.

Comment: I restarted finder on my Mac and it now seems to be working. I never once changed my directory so I have no idea what was causing it.